# R Naive Bayes Output (Confusion Matrix ) Optimization

Tags: r, naivebayes, confusion-matrix

Using the R Naive Bayes package I am trying to find a good model predicting a feature.

Assume I have 12 columns. Assume my train set has 600K rows and test set has 150K rows.

The 12th column (say X) is the one I am trying to predict using the first 11 factor rows.
With the code below

```
nb_model = naiveBayes(train[,1:11], train[,12])
prediction = predict(nb_model,test[,-12])
str(prediction)
length(prediction)
table(pred=prediction,test[,12])
confusionMatrix(prediction,test[,12])
```

I get a low accuracy on TRUE POSITIVES.

```
           Actual False | Actual True
Pred False       115442 |       24862
Pred True          4559 |        5137
```

I have a feeling my TRUE POSITIVES are dominated by FALSE values in the TRAIN set, since the ratio of POSITIVES against ALL VALUES is like 1/5. But PREDICTED TRUE POSITIVES / ALL POSITIVES are even less then 1/5 means worse then random !

The question how can I set some thresholds etc so I can make more TRUE POSITIVE predictions count ? For now I dont care the TP/(TP+NP) rate.

thanks.